# How to use the index of ngFor in ngModel angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

```ts
<div class="row hidden" *ngFor="let q of qu ;let i = index">
  <div class="col-md=12">
    <h2><span class="label label-info"> {{q.ques}}</span></h2>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" [(ngModel)]="'answer'+i" value="{{q.name}}">FOUR
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" [(ngModel)]="'answer'+i" value="Six">SIX
  </div>
</div>

Controller 

answer0:string;
```

How to dynamically binf the index to my ngModel.

Comment: Can you please explain what `"'answer'+i" value="{{q.name}}"` is supposed to do? It's entirely unclear to me.

Comment: ngModel is about binding an element's value to a variable, such that changes in the element's value is reflected in the variable and changes in the variable are reflected in the element.  What are you trying to do with the radio input above? Select a radio button based on the value of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `[]` and `{{}}` together, either one or the other. (`{{}}` is for string interpolation only and the result is always as string)

In the component provide a getter for `this`

```ts
get self() {
  return this;
}
```

```ts
[(ngModel)]="self['answer'+i]"
```